# High lighting 2 cells in Excel if value on another sheet is greater/less than either of the values

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have 2 cells on one sheet in excel that pull in external data. The higher value is in the top cell and the lower value in the lower cell. I want to highlight both cells if a third value on another sheet is greater than the high value or lower than the lower value on the first page.

I have tried using conditional formatting by selecting both cells and making 2 different rules for those 2 cells but it doesn't seem to work. I have tried using the OR function and only making one rule but that hasn't worked either.

Any ideas on the best way to do this? I want both cells to be highlighted.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of both sheets and show what you've tried with the OR formula.

Comment: If not a screenshot, then sample data

Answer (score 0):

Conditional formatting is working fine on my test file :

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's the exact OR formula I used and it wasn't working. I'll have to check to make sure it's able to compare cells that are codes that pull data from the DB.